# Solving system of stochastic DE

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-analysis, stochastic-differential-equations

I am trying to solve the following system of SDEs
$$
\left[ \begin{array}{c}{d X_{1}} \\ {d X_{2}}\end{array}\right]=\left[ \begin{array}{l}{1} \\ {0}\end{array}\right] d t+\left[ \begin{array}{cc}{1} & {0} \\ {0} & {X_{1}}\end{array}\right] \left[ \begin{array}{c}{d W_{1}} \\ {d W_{2}}\end{array}\right]
$$
I would appreciate your comment on my approach and if it is wrong or it can be further solved.

Here is my try: First, I rewrite it in the form
$$
\left\{\begin{array}{l}{d X_{1}(t)=d t+d W_{1}(t)} \\ {d X_{2}(t)=X_{1} d W_{2}(t)}\end{array}\right.
$$
For the first equation, I find 
$$
X_{1}(t)=W_{1}+t+X_{1}(0)
$$
Then I rewrite the second equation as
$$
d X_{2}(t)=(W_{1}+t+X_{1}(0)) d W_{2}(t)
$$
I'm not exactly sure how to proceed from here. Should I just write 
$$
X_{2}(t)=X_{2}(0)+\int_{0}^{t} 0 d s+\int_{0}^{t} (W_{1}+t+X_{1}(0))d W_{2}
$$
$$
X_{2}(t)=X_{2}(0)+(W_{1}+t+X_{1}(0)) W_{2}
$$
? I guess I'm more confused because of the different indexes and how to handle them. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost there. Up to $$dX_2(t)=(W_1(t)+t+X_1(0))dW_2(t)$$ it looks good to me. All you have to do is to write this equation in its integral form (rather than getting rid of "d" from it which is not correct).

Comment: Oh, I missed $X_2(0)$. Does that integration look right?

Comment: The integral form for $X_2$ looks fine to me, though not sure why you included there an integral of $0$. But the formula that follows is not correct.